# Structure types for Json using Web API and FSharp

Tags: json, web-services, f#

I'm create a web service using Web API and fsharp. From the web service I am returning data from a query. (Note that I am using a custom query result type and not one of the standard .Net types, like datatable etc.) That data could be many different "shapes" (i.e. different number of columns etc etc).

Some sample json I'm looking to create would be, e.g.

```
{    
  columns :       
    [
      { field: "FirstName",     title: "First" }, 
      { field: "LastName",      title: "Last" }, 
      { field: "EmailAddress",  title: "Email" },
      { field: "Other",         title: "Other" },
    ],
  data :       
    [
      { FirstName: "A", LastName: "B", EmailAddress: "a@b.c", Other: "zzz" }, 
      { FirstName: "C", LastName: "D", EmailAddress: "c@d.c", Other: "zzz" }, 
      { FirstName: "E", LastName: "F", EmailAddress: "e@f.c", Other: "zzz" } 
    ]      
}
```

but as I say the number of columns will be vary as will their names, data types etc etc.

So far these are my types.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
type QueryColumn = {
    field: string
    title: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
type QueryData = {
    columns: IEnumerable<QueryColumn> 
    data: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string * string>>    
}
```

The above type successfully produces the correct structure of json for the columns element, but not data. I am wondering how I could best structure the "data" type to produce the json structure I am after. I am beginning to wonder whether I may need a type provider so that I can dynamically work out the structure of the query results.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thx

S

Comment: Your data section looks more like a list of map/dictionary, i.e. `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>`.

Comment: @Leaf. Thx. Just having a look at your suggestion. Wow... Appears to works. That's brilliant thx

Comment: Please add the answer as an **answer**. Currently, this question appears in the "unanswered" list, which may be misleading in the future for users with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Leafs suggestion (see comments above), I changed the type definition for QueryData to

```
[<CLIMutable>]
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
type QueryData = {
  columns: IEnumerable<QueryColumn> 
  data: IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,string>>    
}
```

and it works fine.